# MS SQL server datetime field shows UTC timestamp

Tags: sql-server, django

I am new to MS SQL and I am running a Django application on a windows server I have set the TIME_ZONE to my local time zone in the settings.py and in the django admin the time is shown according to the local time zone but in the SQL db the time stamp seems to show the date time format in UTC.
I tried searching how to change the timezone of SQL Server but I don't find any answer on that regard any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you have SQL Server 2016, you can use `AT TIMEZONE`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the timezone of the SQL Server. SQL server will pickup the time form the operating system on which it is running. After changing the time zone on OS the getdate() function automatically return the time according to new time zone setting. So no additional change is required on SQL server. 
Could you please make sure your application and SQL Server ( service of sql server "MSSQLSERVER") are running  on same machine. 
To get the name of machine on which SQL server running you can use below query -

```
select @@SERVERNAME
```